# Error in gzfile(file, "rb") - what should I do?

Tags: r

I'm going to write shortly, because my english is not perfect.

My code is:

```
explanatory=readRDS("explanatory_complete.Rds")
```

And I want knit pdf or word document, I receive this message:

> ```
> Error in gzfile(file, "rb")- can't oppen connection
> ```

Where is problem? I set the right working directory.

Comment: Is there an additional warning message along the lines of `cannot open file 'explanatory_complete.Rds': No such file or directory`?

Comment: No.
There is this: 
<Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> readRDS -> gzfile

Comment: @Vlo, you're probably right. Adrian, could you show us the complete error message. Also verify that it's not `*.rds` or `*.RDS`.

Comment: @Vlo That's the message i am getting. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `explanatory<-readRDS('filename.rds')` this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your case but I ran into

> Error in gzfile(file, "rb")- can't open connection

when I tried to read a large file after it was downloaded using `rsync`. This was due to different file access permissions set by `rsync` than my Windows 10 system. The error was fixed in a local MobaXterm session using

```
chmod u+rwx filename
```

(change filename to your files)

Answer (score 1):

The file likely doesn't exist in your working directory. This often happens to me when I have changed my working directory and forgotten to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving the new R/RMD file first?

I faced the same issue and problem was that, I was not saving the new file first therefore the R session was unable to understand the path for RDS file.

After I saved the file (in the same folder, but not a necessity) and ran the readRDS, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. For me, it was being caused by an update.packages() call in a script my RMD document was sourcing. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but I just put a # in front of this line of code for knitting this RMD and then removed it again after

Answer (score 0):

Check your exact file name and the working directly. it might be .rds missing in your saved file name.